# $f(x+1)=xf(x)$ and $g(x)=\log f(x)$, finding $g''(N+1/2)-g''(N)$

Tags: calculus

My try:
$$f(x+1)=xf(x)\implies f(x+N)=x^Nf(x),N\in\mathbb N$$
Because:
$$f(x+N)=xf(x+N-1)=x^2f(x+N-2)=...x^Nf(x+N-N)=x^Nf(x)$$
Now:
$$\log f(x+N)=N\log x+\log f(x)\\
g(x+N)=N\log x+g(x)\\
g''(x+N)-g''(x)=-\frac{N}{x^2}$$ 
So:
$$g''(N+1/2)-g''(N)=-4N$$
But the answers is: $$-4\sum_{k=1}^N\frac1{(2k- 1)^2}$$

Comment: The second derivative of $x\mapsto N\log(x)$ is $x\mapsto -\frac{N}{x^2}$ and not $x\mapsto-\frac{N^2}{x}$.

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: @Chappers my answer is wrong.

Comment: You might be interested in the digamma function.

Comment: I mean, what is the problem you are trying to solve, precisely?

Comment: The first implication is wrong too.

Comment: @Alamos how is that?

Comment: Can you prove that f is positive making g well defined and that g is twice differentiable? Or are these hypothesis that you "forgot" to add ?

Comment: @Tryss it is already told that f is positive and twice differentiable.

Comment: $f(x+2)=(x+1)f(x+1)=(x+1)xf(x)$, not $=x^2f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK:
$$f(x+N)=(x+N-1)f(x+N-2)=(x+N-1)!f(x)$$
So:
$$g(x+N)-g(x)=\log((x+N-1)!/(x-1)!)$$
So the answer should be:
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N} \log(x+N-k)\right)''\Bigg|_{x=1/2}=\sum_{k=1}^{N-1/2}\frac{-1}{(N-k+1/2)^2}=-4\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac1{(2k-1)^2}$$